# Ошибка в терминале visual studio code: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, visual-studio, scss

Друзья, при попытке запустить gulp-сборку в терминале vs code возникает следующая ошибка:
Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0). You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> .swiper {
> |       overflow: hidden;
> | }

(скриншот 1)

В сборке файл app.js (скрин 2) импортирует slider.js (скрин 3, там же мы определяем будущие класс слайдера), который, в свою очередь, импортирует стили swiper.scss (скрин 4) . Методом проб и ошибок было вычислено, что если закомментировать строчку с импортом стилей (import "../../scss/base/swiper.scss";), то слайдер и вся остальная сборка отлично работают, сайт открывается, но при фронтенд часть со слайдер съезжает и отображается некорректно. Соответствующий для слайдера модуль был подгружен заранее командой: npm i -D swiper . Подскажите, из-за чего может возникать подобная ошибка в терминале и почему vs code не распознает обозначенные заранее классы? Я бьюсь с ней уже несколько недель и ничего не помогает, буду благодарен за любую подсказку.

```js
// app.js
// Функционал

import * as flsFunctions from "./files/functions.js";

/* Проверка поддержки webp, добавление класса webp или no-webp для HTML */
/* (i) необходимо для корректного отображения webp из css  */
flsFunctions.isWebp();
/* Добавление класса touch для HTML если браузер мобильный */
// flsFunctions.addTouchClass();
/* Добавление loaded для HTML после полной загрузки страницы */
// flsFunctions.addLoadedClass();
/* Модуль для работы с меню (Бургер) */
flsFunctions.menuInit();
/* Учет плавающей панели на мобильных устройствах при 100vh */
// flsFunctions.fullVHfix();

/*
Модуль работы со спойлерами
Документация:
Сниппет (HTML): spollers
*/
flsFunctions.spollers();

/*
Модуль работы с табами
Документация:
Сниппет (HTML): tabs
*/
flsFunctions.tabs();

/*
Модуль "показать еще"
Документация по работе в шаблоне:
Сниппет (HTML): showmore
*/
// flsFunctions.showMore();

/*
Попапы
Документация по работе в шаблоне:
Сниппет (HTML): pl
*/
import './libs/popup.js';

/*
Модуль параллакса мышью
Документация по работе в шаблоне:
Сниппет (HTML): 
*/
// import './libs/parallax-mouse.js'

// Работа с формами 
import * as flsForms from "./files/forms/forms.js";

/* Работа с полями формы: добавление классов, работа с placeholder. */
flsForms.formFieldsInit();

/* Oтправка формы со встроенной валидацией полей. false - отключит валидацию */
flsForms.formSubmit(true);

/* Модуль формы "колличество" */
flsForms.formQuantity();

/* Модуль формы "показать пароль" */
// flsForms.formViewpass();

/* Модуль звездного рейтинга */
flsForms.formRating();

/* Модуль работы с select. */
import './libs/select.js'

/* (В работе) Модуль работы с масками.*/
/*
Подключение и настройка выполняется в файле js/files/forms/inputmask.js
Документация по работе в шаблоне:
Документация плагина: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/inputmask
Сниппет(HTML):
*/
// import "./files/forms/inputmask.js";

/* Модуль работы с ползунком */
/*
Подключение и настройка выполняется в файле js/files/forms/range.js
Документация по работе в шаблоне:
Документация плагина: https://refreshless.com/nouislider/
Сниппет (HTML): range
*/
import "./files/forms/range.js";

/* Модуль работы с select. */
import './libs/select.js'

// Модули работы с прокруткой страницы 

/*
Изменение дизайна скроллбара
Документация по работе в шаблоне: В HTML добавляем к блоку атрибут data-simplebar
Документация плагина: https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar
Сниппет(HTML): 
*/
// import './files/scroll/simplebar.js';

// Ленивая (отложенная) загрузка картинок
// Документация по работе в шаблоне: В HTML добавляем img, video, audio, iframe но вместо src пишем data-src
// Документация плагина: https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload
// Сниппет(HTML):
//import './files/scroll/lazyload.js';

// Наблюдатель за объектами c атрибутом data-watch
// Документация по работе в шаблоне: js/libs/watcher.js
// Сниппет(HTML):
// import './libs/watcher.js'

// Функции работы скроллом
import * as flsScroll from "./files/scroll/scroll.js";

// Плавная навигация по странице
// flsScroll.pageNavigation();

// Функционал добавления классов к хедеру при прокрутке
// flsScroll.headerScroll();

// Функционал липкого блока
// flsScroll.stickyBlock();

// Галерея 
/*
Документация по работе в шаблоне: https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/docs/
Документация плагина: https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/docs/
Сниппет(HTML):
*/
// import "./files/gallery.js";

//

// Прочие плагины

/* Динамический адаптив */
import "./libs/dynamic_adapt.js";

/* Форматирование чисел */
// import './libs/wNumb.min.js';

//
// Прочее 

/* Подключаем файлы со своим кодом */
import "./files/script.js";
//===========================================================

import './libs/popup.js';

import './libs/select.js';


// Импортируем слайдер
import "./files/sliders.js";


// slider.js
```

```js
/*
Документация по работе в шаблоне: 
Документация слайдера: https://swiperjs.com/
Сниппет(HTML): swiper
*/

// Подключаем слайдер Swiper из node_modules
// При необходимости подключаем дополнительные модули слайдера, указывая их в {} через запятую
// Пример: { Navigation, Autoplay }
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination, Parallax, Autoplay, Thumbs } from 'swiper';
/*
Основниые модули слайдера:
Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, 
EffectFade, Lazy, Manipulation
Подробнее смотри https://swiperjs.com/
*/

// Стили Swiper
// Базовые стили


// Если закомментировать данную строчку, слайдер будет работать
import "../../scss/base/swiper.scss";


// Полный набор стилей из scss/libs/swiper.scss
// import "../../scss/libs/swiper.scss";
// Полный набор стилей из node_modules
// import 'swiper/css';

// Добавление классов слайдерам
// swiper главному блоку, swiper-wrapper оболочке, swiper-slide для слайдов
function bildSliders() {
    //BildSlider
    let sliders = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="__swiper"]:not(.swiper-wrapper)');
    if (sliders) {
        sliders.forEach(slider => {
            slider.parentElement.classList.add('swiper');
            slider.classList.add('swiper-wrapper');
            for (const slide of slider.children) {
                slide.classList.add('swiper-slide');
            }
        });
    }
}
// Инициализация слайдеров
function initSliders() {
    // Добавление классов слайдера
    // при необходимости отключить
    bildSliders();

    // Перечень слайдеров
    if (document.querySelector('.main-block__slider')) {
        new Swiper('.main-block__slider', {
            // Подключаем модули слайдера
            // для конкретного случая
            modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Parallax, Autoplay],
            // effect: 'fade',
            autoplay: {
                delay: 3000,
                disableOnInteraction: false,
            },
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 50,
            parallax: true,
            // autoHeight: true,
            speed: 800,
            //touchRatio: 0,
            //simulateTouch: false,
            loop: true,
            //preloadImages: false,
            //lazy: true,
            // Dotts
            pagination: {
                el: '.controll-main-block__dotts',
                clickable: true,
            },
            // Arrows
            // navigation: {
            //  nextEl: '.about__more .more__item_next',
            //  prevEl: '.about__more .more__item_prev',
            // },
            /*
            breakpoints: {
                320: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 0,
                    autoHeight: true,
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 20,
                },
                992: {
                    slidesPerView: 3,
                    spaceBetween: 20,
                },
                1268: {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                    spaceBetween: 30,
                },
            },
            */
            on: {
                init: function (swiper) {
                    const allSlides = document.querySelector('.fraction-controll__all');
                    const allSlidesItems = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-main-block:not(.swiper-slide-duplicate)');
                    allSlides.innerHTML = allSlidesItems.length < 10 ? `0${allSlidesItems.length}` : allSlidesItems.length;
                },
                slideChange: function (swiper) {
                    const currentSlide = document.querySelector('.fraction-controll__current');
                    currentSlide.innerHTML = swiper.realIndex + 1 < 10 ? `0${swiper.realIndex + 1}` : swiper.realIndex + 1;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    if (document.querySelector('.products-slider')) {
        new Swiper('.products-slider__slider', {
            // Подключаем модули слайдера
            // для конкретного случая
            modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay],
            // effect: 'fade',
            autoplay: {
                delay: 3000,
                disableOnInteraction: false,
            },
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            watchOverflow: true,
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            parallax: true,
            // autoHeight: true,
            speed: 800,
            //touchRatio: 0,
            //simulateTouch: false,
            //loop: true,
            //preloadImages: false,
            //lazy: true,
            // Dotts
            pagination: {
                el: '.products-slider__dotts',
                clickable: true,
                dynamicBullets: true
            },
            // Arrows
            // navigation: {
            //  nextEl: '.about__more .more__item_next',
            //  prevEl: '.about__more .more__item_prev',
            // },

            breakpoints: {
                320: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 10,
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 20,
                },
                992: {
                    slidesPerView: 3,
                    spaceBetween: 20,
                },
                1370: {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                    spaceBetween: 30,
                },
            },
            on: {
                init: function (swiper) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
    if (document.querySelector('.products-new')) {
        new Swiper('.products-new__slider', {
            // Подключаем модули слайдера
            // для конкретного случая
            modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay],
            // effect: 'fade',
            autoplay: {
                delay: 3000,
                disableOnInteraction: false,
            },
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            watchOverflow: true,
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            parallax: true,
            // autoHeight: true,
            speed: 800,
            //touchRatio: 0,
            //simulateTouch: false,
            //loop: true,
            //preloadImages: false,
            //lazy: true,
            // Dotts
            pagination: {
                el: '.products-new__dotts',
                clickable: true,
                dynamicBullets: true
            },
            // Arrows
            // navigation: {
            //  nextEl: '.about__more .more__item_next',
            //  prevEl: '.about__more .more__item_prev',
            // },

            breakpoints: {
                320: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 10,
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 20,
                },
                992: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 20,
                },
                1330: {
                    slidesPerView: 3,
                    spaceBetween: 30,
                },
            },
            on: {
                init: function (swiper) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
    if (document.querySelector('.thumbs-images')) {
        const thumbsSwiper = new Swiper('.thumbs-images', {
            // Подключаем модули слайдера
            // для конкретного случая
            modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, Thumbs],
            // effect: 'fade',
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            watchOverflow: true,
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 16,
            parallax: true,
            // autoHeight: true,
            speed: 800,
            //touchRatio: 0,
            //simulateTouch: false,
            //loop: true,
            //preloadImages: false,
            //lazy: true,
            // Dotts
            pagination: {
                el: '.products-new__dotts',
                clickable: true,
                dynamicBullets: true
            },
            // Arrows
            // navigation: {
            //  nextEl: '.about__more .more__item_next',
            //  prevEl: '.about__more .more__item_prev',
            // },

            breakpoints: {
                992: {
                    slidesPerView: 3,
                },
                1330: {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                    spaceBetween: 16,
                },
            },
            on: {
                init: function (swiper) {

                }
            }
        });
        new Swiper('.images-product__slider', {
            // Подключаем модули слайдера
            // для конкретного случая
            modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, Thumbs],
            // effect: 'fade',
            autoplay: {
                delay: 3000,
                disableOnInteraction: false,
            },
            thumbs: {
                swiper: thumbsSwiper
            },
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            watchOverflow: true,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            // autoHeight: true,
            speed: 800,
            //touchRatio: 0,
            //simulateTouch: false,
            //loop: true,
            //preloadImages: false,
            //lazy: true,
            // Arrows
            // navigation: {
            //  nextEl: '.about__more .more__item_next',
            //  prevEl: '.about__more .more__item_prev',
            // },
            on: {
                init: function (swiper) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
// Скролл на базе слайдера (по классу swiper_scroll для оболочки слайдера)
function initSlidersScroll() {
    // Добавление классов слайдера
    // при необходимости отключить
    bildSliders();

    let sliderScrollItems = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper_scroll');
    if (sliderScrollItems.length > 0) {
        for (let index = 0; index < sliderScrollItems.length; index++) {
            const sliderScrollItem = sliderScrollItems[index];
            const sliderScrollBar = sliderScrollItem.querySelector('.swiper-scrollbar');
            const sliderScroll = new Swiper(sliderScrollItem, {
                observer: true,
                observeParents: true,
                direction: 'vertical',
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                freeMode: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
                scrollbar: {
                    el: sliderScrollBar,
                    draggable: true,
                    snapOnRelease: false
                },
                mousewheel: {
                    releaseOnEdges: true,
                },
            });
            sliderScroll.scrollbar.updateSize();
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
    // Запуск инициализации слайдеров
    initSliders();
    // Запуск инициализации скролла на базе слайдера (по классу swiper_scroll)
    //initSlidersScroll();
});
```

[image: Ошибка в терминале]
[image: app.js]
[image: slider.js]
[image: swiper.css]

Comment: Замените ваши скрины на код текстом. По скринам очень сложно ориентироваться и не возможно скопировать данные

Comment: Благодарю, код добавил